# User identification

Tags: authentication, rally

I'm very new to Rally (and StackOverflow, for that matter), and I'm trying to build a reporting web app, but only using the Web Services/REST API.
My question is, how does an app know which user you are? Given a username and password, how can I use these to find a certain user? I can't find any object that has a password field.

Here is the link to the REST API: [Rally REST API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/)

Thanks to anybody who can help!

Comment: If your a use in one your a user in both - Correct?
http://developer.rallydev.com/help/rest-api-net

You'll find examples to get you started with the basic Query operations that it provides.  Authentication is done for you. There are a decent number of questions and code examples both here and indeed on the developer site.

Comment: What language/framework is your app going to use? Is it in-browser with html/javascript, or does it run on a server?

Comment: Thank you Johnno, the REST tookit is exactly what I needed.